# Asynchronous database search with AJAX, MVC, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Sorry about the odd question wording. In all honesty I'm in right at the deep end here, having to learn a huge amount all at once.

I'm trying to figure out how to perform an asynchronous search on a database using AJAX, but it keeps coming up with a "500 internal server error". I've done some AJAX tutorials but none of them involve the MVC method of web development. I'm a bit lost with what information needs to be sent where, and how.

All I know is that a 500 Server Error means it's happening on the server side rather than the client side, so I presume there's a break in logic at the point where the controller starts to get involved. That's just a newbie guess though.

I'll paste all of what I believe to be the relevant code. For context, the database info is from an 'accounts' table in a mock bank database I've been working with for practice.

Thanks for any help.

Firstly, here's the error information I get when looking at debug info on Chrome

[image: Internal Server Error 500]

Now here's the code involved.

Javascript/JQuery:

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    var key = 0;

    $j(function () {

        $j("#search_btn").click(function () {
            key = $j("#acc-id-search").val();
            searchAcc();
            return false;
        })        
    });



    function searchAcc() {

        var callback = function (data) {

            $j("#account_data_table").empty();
            var htmlArray = [];
            if (data.total > 0) {
                $j.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                    htmlArray.push("<tr>");
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.account_id + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.product_id + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.cust_id + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.open_date + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.close_date + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.last_activity_date + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.status + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.open_branch_id + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.open_emp_id + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.avail_balance + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push('<td class="text-center">' + item.pending_balance + '</td>');
                    htmlArray.push("</tr>");
                });
            }
            else {
                htmlArray.push('<tr><td colspan="10">No results!</td></tr>');
            }

            $j("#account_data_table").append(htmlArray.join(''));
            alert("Sucess?");

        };
        alert("Searching for '" + key + "'");
        postData('@Url.Content("~/Accounts/Index")', key, callback, '#account_data_table');
    }

    function postData(url, data, callback, lockObj, dataType, loadingMessage)
    {
        data = data || {};
        dataType = dataType || 'json';
        loadingMessage = loadingMessage || 'Loading...';;
        var isLock = !!lockObj;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            method: 'post',
            dataType: dataType,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                alert("About to send");
            },
            success: callback,
            error: function(){
                alert("Failed..!");
            },
            complete: function(){

            }
        });
    }
```

The controller that '@Url.Content("~/Accounts/Index")' points to:

```
[HttpPost]
    public NewtonJsonResult Index(int key)
    {
        var _service = new BankEntities();
        var searchCondition = new account() { account_id = key };
        var resultObj = new AjaxDataResult();
        var allitems = _service.All(searchCondition);
        var itemArray = new JArray();
        resultObj.total = allitems.Count();
        JObject temp;
        foreach(var item in allitems)
        {
            temp = new JObject();
            temp["account_id"] = item.account_id;
            temp["product_cd"] = item.product_cd;
            temp["cust_id"] = item.cust_id;
            temp["open_date"] = item.open_date;
            temp["close_date"] = item.close_date;
            temp["last_activity_date"] = item.last_activity_date;
            temp["status"] = item.status;
            temp["open_branch_id"] = item.open_branch_id;
            temp["open_emp_id"] = item.open_emp_id;
            temp["avail_balance"] = item.avail_balance;
            temp["pending_balance"] = item.pending_balance;
            itemArray.Add(temp);

        }
        resultObj.items = itemArray;
        return new NewtonJsonResult(resultObj);
    }
```

The 'All(searchcondition)' method which is used to find the required items in the table:

```
public List<account> All(account acc)
    {
        var data = accounts.Where(x => x.status == "ACTIVE");
        if(acc.account_id != 0)
        {
            data = data.Where(x => x.account_id == acc.account_id);
        }
        return data.OrderBy(x => x.account_id).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Try removing `dataType: dataType` from ajax, seems like the required param `key` is not getting passed to controller.

Comment: Check your server log it might be your server error.

Comment: @User3250 No luck I'm afraid, still the same problem. Is there a way I can check that the 'key' param is being sent through? I can't figure out how to do a step-by-step debug process on the controller side.

Comment: @RakeshChouhan Where's the server log? In the IDE (I'm on VS2013), or elsewhere?

Comment: @StuartAitken Can you check the browser console to check the exact error response getting returned from server call?

Comment: @User3250 Forgive my incredible noobness here - I'm used to standalone app stuff rather then web stuff so this is all totally new to me - Which part of the console should I be looking at?

Comment: @User3250 The 'network' tab is showing: "Index, Status 500, Type XHR, Initiator jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 "

Comment: @StuartAitken Yes, in network tab in chrome browser, there must be "Response" tab. Pls check while you post it. Or click on the error url in "console" tab should get you to exact error.

Comment: @User3250 - the `dataType` parameter specifies the expected type of the *response*, so it won't affect whether the right values are in the request.

Comment: Stuart - If you are running the server-side code from within your IDE you should be able to set a breakpoint in your `Index()` method and step through to see where it's going wrong. The IDE should also have some kind of console where any C# exceptions would be logged.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ah well now we're getting somewhere. I already tried what you suggested but nothing happened. I figured the debug process was different for web dev stuff, but I've just tried a breakpoint on another method in the controller and it worked. When I put a breakpoint on the Index() method, it doesn't break... So I guess that's where a big problem is happening.

Comment: The method might not be called because you're not setting the right request parameters, so no method exists for the request hence the 500 error. Your current code is trying to include the `key` *value* without giving it a request parameter name. Try changing `key = $j("#acc-id-search").val();` to `key = { key: $j("#acc-id-search").val() };`. (The actual request would then end up with a parameter `key=thesearchvaluehere`.)

Comment: Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response - it will give you the details of the exception

Comment: It also needs to be `data: { key: data }`

Comment: @nnnnnn That worked, you're an absolute hero. Super relieved to find that the logic was overall okay apart from that 'key' parameter. Time for me to inspect that part and get to grips with what I'd missed. You have no idea how grateful I am. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to @nnnnnn whose answer lies in the comments after the initial question:

> The method might not be called because you're not setting the right
>   request parameters, so no method exists for the request hence the 500
>   error. Your current code is trying to include the key value without
>   giving it a request parameter name. Try changing key =
>   $j("#acc-id-search").val(); to key = { key: $j("#acc-id-search").val()
>   };. (The actual request would then end up with a parameter
>   key=thesearchvaluehere.)